# T-SQL grouping by either of two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I hold chat history as follows:

```
Id       From        To        Text         Hour
=================================================
1         A          B         Msg_A_B1     00:01
2         A          B         Msg_A_B2     00:02
3         B          A         Msg_B_A1     00:03
4         A          B         Msg_A_B3     00:05
5         C          A         Msg_C_A1     00:11
6         A          C         Msg_A_C1     00:12
7         C          A         Msg_C_A2     00:14
8         D          B         Msg_D_B1     00:17
```

I want to create a chat header list from data for a spesific user. The rules are

- I want to get the start (first) "Hour" of each chat
- and last message of chat for a spesific user
- ordered by "Hour" ascending

For example if the user is "A" I want to get

```
Correspondant       Text        Hour
=======================================
B                  Msg_A_B3     00:01
C                  Msg_C_A2     00:11
```

Or for user "B" :

```
Correspondant       Text        Hour
=======================================
A                  Msg_A_B3     00:01
D                  Msg_D_B1     00:17
```

I can possibly do it by using Temporary tables, but I am seeking a simpler and faster solution.

This information might lead to the use of Stored Procedures, but a proper use of Views is also accepted.

Comment: What made you think there is an error in data @ZLK? I might have missed it.

Comment: Oh, never mind, it looks like I've misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted the first and last rows for each user but it looks like you're asking for the last [text] but the first [hour] for each individual "correspondent".

Comment: Yes, definetely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is a grouping column to mark a chat between A and B as *"belonging together"* without looking if A or B is the `From` or the `To`.

It is your table design, which makes things difficult. Below my suggestion I will add some hints how this might be done better:

Your *mockup* to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(Id INT,[From] VARCHAR(100),[To] VARCHAR(100),[Text] VARCHAR(100),[Hour] TIME(0))

INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 (1,'A','B','Msg_A_B1','00:01')
,(2,'A','B','Msg_A_B2','00:02')
,(3,'B','A','Msg_B_A1','00:03')
,(4,'A','B','Msg_A_B3','00:05')
,(5,'C','A','Msg_C_A1','00:11')
,(6,'A','C','Msg_A_C1','00:12')
,(7,'C','A','Msg_C_A2','00:14')
,(8,'D','B','Msg_D_B1','00:17');
```

--The query

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t.*
          ,CONCAT(CASE WHEN t.[From]>t.[To] THEN t.[To] ELSE t.[From] END,'-',CASE WHEN t.[From]>t.[To] THEN t.[From] ELSE t.[To] END) AS ChatID
    FROM @mockupTable t
)
,FindFirstAndLast AS
(
    SELECT cte1.ChatID
          ,(SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM cte cte2 WHERE cte2.ChatID=cte1.ChatID ORDER BY cte2.[Hour] ASC) AS FirstId
          ,(SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM cte cte2 WHERE cte2.ChatID=cte1.ChatID ORDER BY cte2.[Hour] DESC) AS LastId
    FROM cte cte1
    GROUP BY cte1.ChatID
)
SELECT fal.ChatID
      ,tFirst.[From] AS FirstFrom 
      ,tFirst.[To] AS FirstTo 
      ,tFirst.[Hour] AS FirstHour 
      ,tLast.[From] AS LastFrom 
      ,tLast.[To] AS LastTo 
      ,tLast.[Text] AS LastText
FROM FindFirstAndLast fal
INNER JOIN @mockupTable tFirst ON fal.FirstId=tFirst.Id
INNER JOIN @mockupTable tLast ON fal.LastId=tLast.Id;
```

The idea in short:

- The first CTE will create a `ChatID` by concatenating the `From` and the `To` in a sorted way. Doing so a message from A to B will get the same ChatID as a message from B to A.
- The second CTE will use a correlated sub-query to find the first and the last message id, grouped for the previously computed ChatID.
- The final SELECT will use these message ids to join the appropriate rows.

The result is coming with everything you need. It's on you, to put it in the format needed:

```
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
| ChatID | FirstFrom | FirstTo | FirstHour | LastFrom | LastTo | LastText |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A-B    | A         | B       | 00:01:00  | A        | B      | Msg_A_B3 |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A-C    | C         | A       | 00:11:00  | C        | A      | Msg_C_A2 |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B-D    | D         | B       | 00:17:00  | D        | B      | Msg_D_B1 |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
```

### Some ideas about the desing

I would use

- one table `Person` for your chatting persons.
- a second table `Chat` for a chat with a ChatID.
- one `m:n` mapping table `ChattingPerson` with JoinTime, a ChatID and a PersonID, both as FKs. Here you can set timestamps like LastAction or mark the status (active, has left, ...)
- one more table `Message` for the messages with time, text, and ChatPersonID as FK.

Your advantages

- The opener can explicitly invite more persons (or limit it to one for a *person2person* chat), or just wait for participants.
- Starting a chat creates the row in the Chat table, the first row in the ChattingPerson table to mark the opener, and eventually a first message row.
- Following messages add - if not existing yet - a row to the ChatPerson (with a new participant) and the message row.
- The ID to the ChatPerson-table will give you the ChatID and the PersonID.
- You can filter per chat and/or by person.
- There can be separate chats between A and B over the time
- You can control the type of chat with a PersonCount-Constraint
- You can enforce, that a new ChatPerson can only be added by the opener
- You can create certain chat types (like *"person2person"*) with a template

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and long description. You have spent some time and I really appreciate that.

I actually use another table for Users.A,B,C,D are actually Foreign Keys, not user names. I just wanted to make things simpler to focus on my problem here.I just don't log activity and exit, but mesages sent wth timestamp.

Your apprach brings a solution to the table but not exactly what I have expected. I was hoping a row with less columns but it still brings a way for me to filter resuts ı need.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it Creating a view:

First let's load the data in table t1:

```
create table t1 (Id int,[From] varchar(10),[To] varchar(10),Text varchar(100),Hour time(0))

insert into t1 values (1,'A','B','Msg_A_B1','00:01')
insert into t1 values (2,'A','B','Msg_A_B2','00:02')
insert into t1 values (3,'B','A','Msg_B_A1','00:03')
insert into t1 values (4,'A','B','Msg_A_B3','00:05')
insert into t1 values (5,'C','A','Msg_C_A1','00:11')
insert into t1 values (6,'A','C','Msg_A_C1','00:12')
insert into t1 values (7,'C','A','Msg_C_A2','00:14')
insert into t1 values (8,'D','B','Msg_D_B1','00:17')
```

Then let's create the view

```
create view vChats
as 
with cte as (
select  left([text],len([text])-1) as chat,
        t.*
from t1 as t
),
cte2 as (
select chat,
        min(hour) as minHour,
        max(text) as maxText
from cte
group by chat
),
cte3 as (select distinct [From] as [User] 
            from t1 
         UNION 
         select distinct [To] as [User] 
            from t1
)
select c3.[User],
        t.[To] as Correspondant,
        c.maxText as [Text],
        c.minHour as [Hour]
from cte2 as c
    inner join t1 as t ON c.maxText = t.[Text]
    inner join cte3 as c3 ON c3.[User] = t.[From]
UNION
select c3.[User],
        t.[From] as Correspondant,
        c.maxText as [Text],
        c.minHour as [Hour]
from cte2 as c
    inner join t1 as t ON c.maxText = t.[Text]
    inner join cte3 as c3 ON c3.[User] = t.[To]
```

After that you can use to get all the communications for each user like this:

```
select *
from vChats
where [User] = 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer but this does not exatly d what I need. I still get two rows for the chat between A and B. I want to see only one row A, B, Last chat, First chat hour.